# How to pop any character from string using python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I wanna remove the first ".." from the below code:

```
new_str = "../jsp/data.json?kjhgf="
```

I can't use replace method. Because it'll remove all the "." . Which I don't want. Does anyone know to do this?

Comment: You _can_ use `.replace("../","/")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [string slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
 new_str[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer?

```
removed_string = new_string[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's replace method has a max replace argument. Example:

```
>>> new_str = "../jsp/data.json?kjh..gf="
>>>
>>> new_str.replace("..", "", 1)
'/jsp/data.json?kjh..gf='
```

Docs : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

just

```
A=new_str[2:]
```

Try this, hope so it may help